# "Hostname could not be parsed" From "ftp" URL

Tags: c#

I just purchased some online storage from GoDaddy and I an trying to FTP into my storage account. The thing is, I can view and modify my account using FileZilla, but my C Sharp program will not even access it because of the "hostname could not be parsed" error.

I believe it is because the entire ftp address of my account has two "@" signs in the url, and  it is the wreaking havoc in the URI creation process.

Is there anyway I can get around this, or am I screwed because of the naming convention of the GoDaddy storage?

The URL is: ftp:[slashslash]lastname.firstname@gmail.com@onlinefilefolder.com/Home/

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? Do you have any example code? Exactly what is the format of the godaddy hostname you're passing in?

Comment: The URL is:  ftp://lastname.firstname@gmail.com@onlinefilefolder.com/Home/The%20Files/accounts%20name.txt

Comment: URIs can have `@` it is a reserved delimiter character.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2  It seems your parser is not so good.

Comment: Can you add some code that can be looked at/debugged?

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to specify the username and password in the URI for some specific reason? You can simply connect to the host and then provide credentials.

```
// Create a request to the host
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://onlinefilefolder.com");

// Set the username and password to use
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("lastname.firstname@gmail.com","password");

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

var sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
var fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

response.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception is originating from `System.Uri`, which (despite it being acceptable by the standards definition) will not allow two `@` symbols.

```
// This will reproduce the reported exception, I assume it is what your code is
// doing either explicitly, or somewhere internally
new Uri(@"ftp://lastname.firstname@gmail.com@onlinefilefolder.com/Home/")
```

A potential workaround is to percent-encode the first `@` symbol, which will allow the `Uri` instance to be instantiated without exception--but may or may not work depending on the server's behavior (I have only used this approach a couple times, but it has worked for me):

```
new Uri(@"ftp://lastname.firstname%40gmail.com@onlinefilefolder.com/Home/")
```

Comment: Your suggestion has stopped the the error and my program even "successfully" uploads to my online storage account, but whenever I go there with FileZilla, the file is not actually there. It seems that the percent-encoding is not a viable option for me.